# APEX unit test for lead trigger error : "Invalid field subject for Sobject Lead"

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, error-messages

I have an error message for a test class that i try to create for 2 triggers. 
The error message is: "Invalid field subject for Sobject Lead" .

Can anyone look at this and tell me what i do wrong , please ?

The first trigger is here:

```
trigger leadRoundRobin on Lead (before insert, before update) {

 //Check if assignment owner has changed
 //
 Map<Integer,Id> queueIds = new Map<Integer,Id>();   //Trigger index --> Queue ID

Integer idx = 0;
for (Lead l : Trigger.new)
{
if(Trigger.isUpdate) {  
    if(l.OwnerId <> Trigger.oldMap.get(l.id).OwnerId) {
        if (l.TempOwnerId__c == 'SKIP') {
            Trigger.new[idx].TempOwnerId__c = '';
        } else {
            queueIds.put(idx, l.OwnerId);
        }
    }           
}else {
    queueIds.put(idx, l.OwnerId);
}   
idx++;
}
System.debug('>>>>>queueIds: '+queueIds);
if (queueIds.isEmpty()) return;

//
//Find active Assignment Group for Queue
//
Map<Integer,Id> asgnGroupNameIds = new Map<Integer,Id>();   //Trigger index --> Assignment_Group_Name ID
Map<Id,Assignment_Group_Queues__c> asgnGroupQueues = new Map<Id,Assignment_Group_Queues__c>(); //Queue ID --> Assignment Group Queues

for(Assignment_Group_Queues__c[] agq : [SELECT Assignment_Group_Name__c, QueueId__c
                                  FROM Assignment_Group_Queues__c 
                                  WHERE QueueId__c in :queueIds.values()
                                  AND Active__c = 'True'])
{
for (Integer i = 0; i < agq.size() ; i++) {
    asgnGroupQueues.put(agq[i].QueueId__c, agq[i]);
}                                           
}
System.debug('>>>>>asgnGroupQueues: '+asgnGroupQueues); 
if (asgnGroupQueues.isEmpty()) return;

for (Integer i : queueIds.keySet()) {
Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq = asgnGroupQueues.get(queueIds.get(i));

if (agq <> null) {
    asgnGroupNameIds.put(i, agq.Assignment_Group_Name__c);
}
//else no active assignment group queue error
}
System.debug('>>>>>asgnGroupNameIds: '+asgnGroupNameIds);
if (asgnGroupNameIds.isEmpty()) return;

//
//Determine next valid user in Queue/Assignment Group for round robin
//User with earliest last assignment date wins.
//
Map<Id,Assignment_Groups__c[]> asgnGroups = new Map<Id,Assignment_Groups__c[]>(); // Assignment Group Name ID --> User ID
for(Assignment_Groups__c[] ags : [SELECT Group_Name__c, User__c, Last_Assignment__c, Millisecond__c 
                           FROM Assignment_Groups__c 
                           WHERE Group_Name__c in :asgnGroupNameIds.values() 
                           AND Active__c = 'True' AND User_Active__c = 'True'
                           ORDER BY Last_Assignment__c, Millisecond__c])
{
if (ags.size()>0) {
    asgnGroups.put(ags[0].Group_Name__c, ags);
}
}
System.debug('>>>>>asgnGroups: '+asgnGroups);   
if (asgnGroups.isEmpty()) return;

Map<Id,Assignment_Groups__c> updateAssignmentGroups = new Map<Id,Assignment_Groups__c>();
Map<Id, datetime> latestAGDateTime = new Map<Id,datetime>();
idx = 0;    
for (Integer i : queueIds.keySet())
{
Assignment_Groups__c[] ags = asgnGroups.get(asgnGroupNameIds.get(i));
if (ags.size()>0)
{   
    //Choose next user in line if user ID has already been used but not committed in this trigger batch 
    Assignment_Groups__c ag = ags[math.mod(idx, ags.size())];

    //Assign User to Lead as the new owner
    System.debug('>>>>>Owner changed for Lead ' + Trigger.new[i].Id + ' from '+Trigger.new[i].OwnerId+' to '+ ag.User__c);
    Trigger.new[i].OwnerId = ag.User__c;    
    Trigger.new[i].TempOwnerId__c = '';  // don't assign back in an endless loop

    //Set last assignment datetime
    datetime now = datetime.now();
    ag.Last_Assignment__c = now;
    ag.Millisecond__c = now.millisecondGMT();

    //update only latest Assignment Groups per ID
    if (latestAGDateTime.containsKey(ag.id)) {
        if(latestAGDateTime.get(ag.id) < now) {
            updateAssignmentGroups.put(ag.id, ag);
            latestAGDateTime.put(ag.id, now);
        }
    } else {
        updateAssignmentGroups.put(ag.id, ag);
        latestAGDateTime.put(ag.id,now);
    }

    idx++;
}
 }
 //Map --> List/Array for DML update
  List<Assignment_Groups__c> updateAG = new List<Assignment_Groups__c>();
   for (Id agId : updateAssignmentGroups.keySet()) {
updateAG.add(updateAssignmentGroups.get(agId));
}

System.debug('>>>>>Update Assignment Groups: '+updateAG);   

//
//Update last assignment for Assignment Group in batch
//
if (updateAG.size()>0) {
try {
    update updateAG;
} catch (Exception e){
    for (Integer i : queueIds.keySet())
    {
        Trigger.new[i].addError('ERROR: Could not update Assignment Group records ' + '     DETAIL: '+e.getMessage());  
    }
}
}
}
```

The second trigger is:

```
     // leadOwnerUpdate.trigger:

trigger leadOwnerUpdate on Lead (after update) {
List<Lead> updateLeads = new List<Lead>();
Map<Id,Lead> leads = new Map<Id,Lead>();
for (Lead l : Trigger.new)
{
if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
System.debug('>>>>> Owner ID: '+l.ownerId+' Temp Owner ID: '+ l.TempOwnerId__c);
if(l.TempOwnerId__c <> null && l.TempOwnerId__c <> '') {
if(l.OwnerId <> l.TempOwnerId__c) {
leads.put(l.id,l);
}
}
}
}
if (leads.isEmpty()) return;
 for (Lead l : [SELECT OwnerId,TempOwnerId__c FROM Lead WHERE id in :leads.keySet()]) {
l.OwnerId = leads.get(l.Id).TempOwnerId__c;
l.TempOwnerId__c = 'SKIP'; //flag to stop infinite loop upon update
updateLeads.add(l);
}
System.debug('>>>>>Update Leads: '+updateLeads);
//
//Update last assignment for Assignment Group in batch
//
if (updateLeads.size() > 0) {
try {
update updateLeads;
} catch (Exception e){

}
}
}
```

And the test class is here :

```
@isTest
private class TestMethodLead{

static testMethod void myTest11() {

    // This code runs as the system user

    User u1;

    try{
      u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
    } catch (QueryException qe){

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

    for(User u : users){
        if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
          u1 = u;
          break;
    }
    }

    }

    System.debug(u1);

   //*****Create Queue 

   Group testGroup = new Group ();
   testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
   testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
   insert testGroup;

   QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
   testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
   testQueue.SObjectType = 'Lead';
   insert testQueue;

   // Second Queue       
   Group testGroup2 = new Group ();
   testGroup2.Name = 'TestQueue2';
   testGroup2.Type = 'Queue';
   insert testGroup2;

   QueueSObject testQueue2 = new QueueSObject();
   testQueue2.QueueId = testGroup2.id;
   testQueue2.SObjectType = 'Lead';
   insert testQueue2;


   test.starttest();

    //Run test

    //Assign Case with out any Assignment Groups
   Lead c1 = new Lead (subject='testlead',TempOwnerID__c=testGroup2.id, OwnerID=u1.id); //tempOwnerID__c=testGroup2.id,  
    insert c1;
    update c1;


    //Create Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Lead');
    insert ag1;


    //Add bad queue name
    Assignment_Group_Queues__c agqBad = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name='Bad Queue',Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );

    try {
        insert agqBad; 
    } catch (DmlException e){
         System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'), e.getMessage()); 

    } //catch

    test.stoptest();

}

static testMethod void myTest2() {

    // This code runs as the system user

    User u1;

    try{
      u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
    } catch (QueryException qe){

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

    for(User u : users){
        if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
          u1 = u;
          break;
    }
    }

    }

    System.debug(u1);

   //*****Create Queue 

   Group testGroup = new Group ();
   testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
   testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
   insert testGroup;

   QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
   testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
   testQueue.SObjectType = 'Lead';
   insert testQueue;

   // Second Queue       
   Group testGroup2 = new Group ();
   testGroup2.Name = 'TestQueue2';
   testGroup2.Type = 'Queue';
   insert testGroup2;

   QueueSObject testQueue2 = new QueueSObject();
   testQueue2.QueueId = testGroup2.id;
   testQueue2.SObjectType = 'Lead';
   insert testQueue2;


   test.starttest();

    //Run test


    //Create Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Lead');
    insert ag1;        

    //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
    insert agq1;


    //Add User to Assignment Groups Users
    Assignment_Groups__c agu1 = new Assignment_Groups__c (User__c = u1.id, Active__c='True', Group_Name__c = ag1.id, Last_Assignment__c = datetime.valueOf('2009-01-01 21:13:24') );
    insert agu1;

    Lead c2 = new Lead (subject='testcase', tempOwnerID__c=testGroup2.id , OwnerID=testGroup.id); //Set owner ID to Queue
    insert c2;
    update c2;        

    test.stoptest();

}

static testMethod void myTest3() {

    // This code runs as the system user

    User u1;

    try{
      u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
    } catch (QueryException qe){

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

    for(User u : users){
        if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
          u1 = u;
          break;
    }
    }

    }

    System.debug(u1);

   //*****Create Queue 

   Group testGroup = new Group ();
   testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
   testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
   insert testGroup;

   QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
   testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
   testQueue.SObjectType = 'Lead';
   insert testQueue;

   test.starttest();

    //Run test        

    //Create Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Lead');
    insert ag1;        

    //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
    insert agq1;


    //Add User to Assignment Groups Users
    Assignment_Groups__c agu1 = new Assignment_Groups__c (User__c = u1.id, Active__c='True', Group_Name__c = ag1.id, Last_Assignment__c = datetime.valueOf('2009-01-01 21:13:24') );
    insert agu1;      

    Lead c3 = new Lead (subject='testcase', OwnerID=testGroup.id); //Set owner ID to Queue
    insert c3;
    update c3;

    test.stoptest();

}

static testMethod void myTest4() {

    // This code runs as the system user

    User u1;

    try{
      u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
    } catch (QueryException qe){

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

    for(User u : users){
        if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
          u1 = u;
          break;
    }
    }

    }

    System.debug(u1);

   //*****Create Queue 

   Group testGroup = new Group ();
   testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
   testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
   insert testGroup;

   QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
   testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
   testQueue.SObjectType = 'Lead';
   insert testQueue;


   test.starttest();

    //Run test

    //Create Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Lead');
    insert ag1;        

    //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
    insert agq1;

      //Test for AG-Queues already assigned to another Assignment Group
    Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq2 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
    try {
        insert agq2;
    } catch (DmlException e){
         System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'), e.getMessage()); 
    } //catch

    test.stoptest();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the source of your problem with your test class:

```
Lead c3 = new Lead (subject='testcase', OwnerID=testGroup.id); //Set owner ID to Queue
```

Look up the valid field names for Lead and you'll see that `subject` is not one of them.